# How to apply scalePagesToFit in another lifecycle moment in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, lifecycle

I am making some simple view based on webView. I wanted to call `scalePagesToFit = true` simply in `viewDidLoad` but this didn't work properly. The views that I wanted to fit - were ok, but views that were already showed properly (with no need to resize), have been resized and stretched - and this is what I wanted to avoid. That's the reason I added checking if loaded content is wider than screen.

```
private var needsResize: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if self.needsResize == true {
                self.webView.scalesPageToFit = true
            } else {
                self.webView.scalesPageToFit = false
            }}}

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.delegate = self
        self.webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 20
        self.webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5

       (...)
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        let scrollWidth = self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.width
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let screenWidght = screenSize.width

        if scrollWidth > screenWidght {
            self.needsResize = true
        }
    }
```

The main problem is the lifecycle is not working in my favor here. I can measure the content just before `viewWillAppear` and after `viewDidLoad`.
I tried to put it in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` but it didn't seem to work - mainly because the `scalesPagesToFit` didn't work. The only working so-so solution was putting `viewDidLoad` in `didSet`. But You can guess how it was working - the whole view was blinking and reloading for content wider than screen.
Do You have any ideas or hints for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that by moving making new method called e.g. `loadWebContent()`.
I move everything webview loading related here so it's like that

```
loadWebContent(){
 self.webView.loadHTMLString(text, baseURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath))
}
```

Then it's called once in `viewDidLoad` than second time in `didSet`. And `didSet` has been rewritten and simplified.

```
  didSet {
     self.webView.scalesPageToFit = self.needsResize
     loadWebContent()
}
```

Simple as that! I hope that will help someone.